# Common elements of vectors with multiple elements

Tags: r, vector, intersection

How to efficiently find common elements of two vectors with duplicate elements?

Example:

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)  
v2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5)  
commonElements <- c(1, 1, 3, 4)
```

`intersect` doesn't handle duplicate elements well.

Comment: Do both vectors have an equal length?

Comment: No, it can't be assumed. They are also not sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `intersect` and `table`s, so...

```
tv1 <- table(v1)
tv2 <- table(v2)
comvals <- intersect(names(tv1),names(tv2))
comtab <- apply(rbind(tv1[comvals],tv2[comvals]),2,min)
```

The information is still there, but in (what I view as) a nicer format:

```
> comtab
1 3 4 
2 1 1
```

EDIT: If you really want that vector, though, it's: `as.numeric(rep(names(comtab),comtab))`.

Comment: +1 - I'd suggest `comtab <- c(pmin(tv1[comvals], tv2[comvals]))`. Well, now I see that's exactly what @Carson did.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option:

```
common <- function(v1, v2) {
  lvls <- unique(c(v1, v2))
  v1a <- factor(v1, levels=lvls)
  v2a <- factor(v2, levels=lvls)
  v <- pmin(table(v1a), table(v2a))
  as.numeric(rep(names(v), v))
}

common(rep(1:3, 1:3), rep(1:2, 1:2))
[1] 1 2 2

common(rep(c(1,3,5), 1:3), rep(c(5,2), 2))
[1] 5 5
```

EDIT: wrap a function, demonstrate different cases and speed up per @Dason's comment

Comment: @Roland you sure about that?  Seems to work on vectors of different lengths for me.  It won't be sorted but it works for me.  Unless I didn't try enough test cases...

Comment: Ahh, that's what creating the factors explicitly is for. +1

Comment: With that said a basic speed up could be gained by only computing `unique(v1, v2)` a single time instead of twice.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this but I opted to sort it and use `rle` to get the values and counts.  `table` could probably accomplish the same task as well.

```
common <- function(v1, v2){
  r1 <- rle(sort(v1))
  r2 <- rle(sort(v2))
  vals <- intersect(r1$values, r2$values)
  l1 <- r1$lengths[r1$values %in% vals]
  l2 <- r2$lengths[r2$values %in% vals]
  rep(vals, pmin(l1, l2))
}

common(v1, v2)
```

some examples

```
> common(v1, v2)
[1] 1 1 3 4
> common(c(1,1), c(3,2,1,3,1))
[1] 1 1
> common(c(1,2,3,2), c(1,2,3))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: It works, but I need to use this function heavily and I'm a bit concerned about the efficiency. Your solution uses: 2 * rle, 2 * sort, 2 * %in% and 1 * intersection. I was hoping that there is a bit clever way of making this.

Comment: Well you never mentioned efficiency in the problem so I offered this up as a first attempt.  But then again with no guarantees about equal length vectors or if the vectors are sorted or any other knowledge about the vectors themselves... well you could always use Rcpp if you want speed ups...  But with that said this solution seems to work fairly quickly for me even with large vectors.

Comment: I mentioned efficiency at the very beginning of the question: "How to efficiently ...". I will test efficiency of Your solution. Thanks!