# comparison of two sets when repeated in r

Tags: r, set

I would like to compare two sets efficiently and using setdiff and intersect functions, but is not working the way I wanted to. I would like to compare the elements of two sets and see if which elements are different.

for example:

```
Aset = c("AAAAA", "AABBB", "AAABB", "BBBBB")
Bset = c("AAABB" ,"AAABB", "BBBAA", "BBBBB")

 # present in Aset but not in Bset 
setdiff(Aset, Bset)
[1] "AAAAA" "AABBB"

#present in Bset but not in Aset 
setdiff(Bset, Aset)
[1] "BBBAA"

# both in Aset in Bset 
intersect (Aset, Bset)
[1] "AAABB" "BBBBB"
```

However when I repeated values, this will consider this as one element (which is correct mathematically) but I want to see how many elements match without considering duplications.

```
Cset = c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "AAABB", "BBBBB")
Dset = c("AAABB" ,"AAABB", "ABBBB", "BBBBB")

 # present in Aset but not in Bset 
setdiff(Cset, Dset)
[1] "AAAAA"
```

There is one more BBBB in set Cset over the Dset. So I am want a alternate function that can consider duplicated values and give something like this:

```
  [1] "AAAAA"  "BBBBB"
```

The intersect also show similar behavior (which correct by definition).

```
Eset = c("AAAAA", "BBBBB", "AAAAA", "BBBBB")
Fset = c("BBBBB" ,"AAAAA", "BBBBB", "AAAAA")

intersect (Eset, Fset) 
[1] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"
```

What I would like to see that all four are matching.

```
[1] "AAAAA" "BBBBB"  "AAAAA" "BBBBB"
```

***Looking for alternate function - that fit my need*** ..

Comment: "Each of union, intersect, setdiff and setequal will discard any duplicated values in the arguments, and they apply as.vector to their arguments (and so in particular coerce factors to character vectors)."

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388405/common-elements-of-vectors-with-multiple-elements-in-r